# Bonding and then breaking radioactive molecules

Tags: bond, molecules, radioactivity

I was looking at [Radon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon) and noticed that it has a half-life of 3.8 days, yet still makes compounds with some other elements.

This got me wondering, are there any examples of chemical processes or industrial processes, where a radioactive material is bonded into a molecule, with the knowledge that its going to decay relatively "soon" (minutes <-> days)?  Ex: I know Radon will decay in 3.8 days, so I bond it with Fluorine, send it somewhere, and then let it decay into its final decay state.

Other reasons might be:

- Favorable energy characteristics (ex: exothermic to bond, and then exothermic products after it decays and breaks).
- Favorable breakdown results (ex: the decays itself causes a reaction, or the resulting molecule after decay is no longer stable and spontaneously breaks, or the decay results in a desired molecule with the final bonded decay products)
- Favorable physical characteristics (ex: good way to transport some material somewhere and then let it decay and naturally separate)

Have not found any examples in searching yet, although may just not know the words to search

Comment: Search for "hot atom chemistry" and I think you'll find some relevant results.

Comment: While Radon-222 has a _half life_ of 3.8 days, that does not mean that any given Radon-222 atom _will_ decay in 3.8 days. It means that only roughly half will decay in that time and you don't know which.

Comment: And do you count nuclear medicine, e.g. for PET scans?

Comment: @Anger Density Thank you for the reference on "hot atom chemistry."  Found a couple summary papers and that looks like what I'm considering.  Most stuff is really old though, so I guess it must not be a very active field.  Jon Custer, the PET scan idea is similar, its just using/detecting the decay particle, rather the resulting molecule after decay.

Comment: That's rather broad. Some molecules were synthesized via decay. Some isotopes are useful because they make other ones, etc.

Comment: In terms of my question, I was mostly interested in the case of isotope + bond -> molecule.  Then isotope decays while part of molecule, resulting in interesting or valuable effect.

Comment: So something like "Fludeoxyglucose F18 (FDG) is a positron-emitting radiotracer used with positron emission tomography (PET)" - although that is often made in-situ in the molecule by the O18(p,n)F18 nuclear reaction. The glucose goes to regions of high metabolic activity in the body such as cancer tumors, and the positron emission results in electron-positron annihilation and detection of the gammas to localize the tumor.

Comment: That's a fair argument on Fludeoxyglucose F18.  It does specifically go to regions of the body that are relevant, only because it has been bonded into the molecular form, and as a free isotope, it would not have nearly the utility.  And the resulting decay does produce an interesting or valuable effect.